# LINQ to Entities grouped logical operations in Where

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to execute the following linq query and it seems to be ignoring order of operations. (Parentheses first)

```
var result = _repo.Transactions.Where(t => 
                      t.DateEntered > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7) 
                      && ( t.TranDesc != "BALANCE FORWARD" && t.Withdrawl == 0 && t.Deposit == 0 ) );
```

Here's the where clause that generates:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[dateentered] > (DATEADD (day, -7, SysDateTime()))) 
AND (N'BALANCE     FORWARD' <> [Extent1].[TranDesc]) 
AND (cast(0 as decimal(18)) = [Extent1].[Withdrawl]) 
AND (cast(0 as decimal(18)) = [Extent1].[Deposit])
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is actually what I wanted and it solved my problem. Just didn't think it all the way though. Thanks.

```
var result = _repo.Transactions.Where(t => 
                      t.dateentered > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7) 
                      && ((t.TranDesc == "BALANCE FORWARD" && (t.Withdrawl != 0 || t.Deposit != 0))
                      || (t.TranDesc != "BALANCE FORWARD")));
```

Comment: When you are executing this query, are you getting any error..?? or the result which you are getting, is that wrong..??

Comment: I couldn't spot any practical differences between LINQ and generated SQL. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: `Parentheses first` How does it matter? Conditions don't change state of anything.

Comment: I realize now that I must be doing something really silly. I recognize that the parenthesis don't matter in this case since all operations are &&.  What I'm trying to get is all Transactions within the last 7 days where the description <> "BALANCE FORWARD" unless is also has a non zero withdrawal/deposit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `a && (b && c && d)` and `a && b && c && d`, and that's why parentheses within generated SQL are not exactly the same as in your LINQ query. But at the end there is no difference between these queries.